# Feasibility of fin drive

Tags: fluid-dynamics, propulsion

For marine propulsion, propellers/screws are de rigeur.  Unfortunately, they are also very hazardous to marine life.  I understand that alternatives like water jets and even MHD drives exist, but I am curious about the feasibility of a biology-inspired motor comprised of reciprocating fins, like the tail fin of a marlin, etc.

I am less concerned about direct efficiency comparisons to screws, and more interested in whether such drives are realistic at all.  Obviously, a single fin would cause a lateral oscillation which is undesirable, but a pair of fins in opposition should at least cancel each other's lateral movements, albeit at the expense of possibly causing other undesirable turbulence effects.  I imagine that a catamaran hull would be like having two very large fish rigidly attached to each other at some appropriate distance, which in my mind seems very feasible, but I have not seen any discussion of the mechanics of such a thing.

I assume that fins might be competitive at low speeds, losing out to props at high speeds (say, 30+ knots).  Would they be feasible for ferries?  Small container ships?  Panamax?  The biggest LNG freighters?  I'm not sure how to even ballpark the average mileage of such a drive at the typical freighter speed of 25 knots or so.

For now, let's define "feasible" as: "can achieve 25 knots with less than 200% of today's specific fuel consumption for mainstream engines."  If answers only apply to ships in a certain size range, I am still interested, but would like to see an explanation of the constraints/limitations.

Comment: Somewhat different than what you seek, but there are wave-powered ships. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_power_ship

Comment: It sounds like your one and only argument in favor of a 'fin drive' is that it would be less "hazardous to marine life". Is that correct? If so, it seems like a rather weak motivation since I'm sure that there are ways of minimizing the danger of propellor driven boats to marine life by, say, shrouding or recessing the propellor. Also, as for a 'fin drive' being less hazardous to marine life, if I were a dolphin I don't think that I would want to be hit by a fin drive of a boat speeding along at 25 knots so I'm skeptical that it's really significantly less hazardous than a propellor.

Comment: Here's a low-speed version: https://www.hobie.com/miragedrive/

Comment: @SamuelWeir Dolphins can swim up to 20 kts for short distances, and nobody has complained about them being a marine hazard (except for the prey fish, of course).  But propellers are deadly even at low boat speeds, and shrouds won't stop small fish from getting blended.

Comment: @D.Halsey The Mirage Drive looks super awesome!  Obviously, fin drives work up to the size of blue whales, so it seems like a reasonable design for ships at least up to large sailboat size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An MIT research project demonstrated this with "[Proteus the Penguin Boat](https://techtv.mit.edu/videos/650-proteus-the-penguinboat)" which is a small boat that uses two opposed vertical rudder-like fins that move inward and outward. However, it's no more than a small testbed project.

This general kind of thing -- heavy, high-power reciprocating surfaces -- tends to be difficult to engineer to be both efficient and reliable especially at large scale, and inevitably has a lot more moving parts than a simple propeller shaft.

[Their paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/oscillating-foils-of-high-propulsive-efficiency/22E5CD028D92318AFC88ED104E55786B) claims they achieved "87 percent" efficiency but it's not clear if that can be compared to current commercial running gear.

Comment: Interesting that reciprocating fins are potentially more efficient than props.  I've seen estimates that props achieve about 50% of the theoretically possible efficiency (I presume that means only 50% of the input energy gets converted to actual thrust).

Comment: That seems a bit low to me but I'm going on nothing but intuition. 

Probably that would mean that 50 percent of their input energy goes to "actuator disk work". 

(Even in spherical (irrotational inviscid) cow land, the physics of a propeller are surprisingly complicated.)